# Create a folder each time I reload the page in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a folder with a unique name in which all the files thats been uploaded by the user will be saved for the particular session. But now the folder creation is happening only when I start the server I want this to happen each time refresh the browser.

My Server.js code:

```
const express = require('express'); const app = express(); // const    reload = require('reload');
       // var ReactComponent = require('./example.jsx');
       app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)    app.use(express.static('./'))
       // Call the multerImpl and pass in app state to it    require('./src-server/multerImpl')(app)
       // reload(app);
       module.exports = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'))      console.log('Visit http://localhost:' + app.get('port')) })
```

Node File where the folder is created:

```
const number = Math.random();

  var dir = './uploads/'+number+'';

  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);

    console.log('Folder Created');
}
const testFolder = dir;
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/'+number+'',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      // Mimetype stores the file type, set extensions according to filetype
      switch (file.mimetype) {

        case '.stl':
            ext = '.stl';
            break;
      }

      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  });
  const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your folder creation logic inside route.
For example if you want to create folder on "/" request then put your code inside "/" route

So, each time "/" requested folder will be created

Comment: In the "/" can I use a variable that is accessible in other links also?

Comment: yes, you can do with [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) 
 or share session variable

Comment: I tried using "/' but on calling its not creating the folder

Comment: is there any error?? or what?? can you give me the code which you write after I gave you a solution...

Comment: app.post('/', function(req, res){
    const number = Math.random();

    var dir = './uploads/'+number+'';
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  
      console.log('Folder Created');
  }
});